# Can i use something like Model.find(params[:id]) in a model.rb file? - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could one kindly advise me how one defines the below code in the controller file in a `model.rb` file

```
events_controller.rb
event = Event.find(params[:id])
```

> how would one write the code `event = Event.find(params[:id])` in a
>   `user.rb` file?

i am unsure: i tried the below in the user.rb model file but no success:

```
def access?
    event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    self.email == event.user.email
  end
```

Comment: you cannot access `params` in model

Comment: what do you want? the model file is a models/event.rb?

Comment: i want to define an event in the user.rb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can make some like

```
#models/user.rb
...
def access( event_id )
    event = Event.find( event_id )
    self.email == event.user.email
end
```

and call from any controller like

```
User.access( event.id )
```